# or-tools 9.6: Error in the routing search parameters built from flags

Tags: c++, or-tools

I updated or-tools from 7.5 to 9.6 (using `or-tools_x64_VisualStudio2019_cpp_v9.6.2534.zip`), and now I am getting the the following error when I execute some routing routines that used to work fine in 7.5:

```
E0000 00:00:1683810900.419419   27176 routing_flags.cc:330] Error in the routing search parameters built from flags: local_search_neighborhood_operator.use_shortest_path_swap_active should be set to BOOL_TRUE or BOOL_FALSE instead of BOOL_UNSPECIFIED (value: 0)
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Which language are you using ? C++ ? python, java, C# ? How do you get parameters? The recommended way is first to query the default parameters through DefaultRoutingModelParameters() or DefaultRoutingSearchParameters(), then modify these parameters.

Comment: I am using C++, and I use the following: RoutingSearchParameters parameters = BuildSearchParametersFromFlags();

Comment: It seems the BuildSearchParametersFromFlags does not set that parameter. You can set manually it just after.

Comment: I tried that before posting this. I get the following error: error C2039: 'set_use_shortest_path_swap_active': is not a member of 'operations_research::RoutingSearchParameters'

Comment: routing_search_parameters->mutable_local_search_operators()->set_use_shortest_path_swap_active(BOOL_TRUE);

Comment: Thanks Laurent, that worked. The results of the solver are now correct. The only minor issue is that it still shows the error above, as soons as  BuildSearchParametersFromFlags() is called, which can raise a false alarm as it shows up in the program output...

Comment: THis is a bug. We will fix it. But at least, you have a workaround.